# float not working in if else statement (c)

Tags: c, if-statement, int

Whenever I try to use a float value in this `IF ELSE statement` it gives me `0` or an incorrect answer. I have used `INT` for the rest of the code and the rest works fine. This is the first time I have used float in the code and now it's not giving me the answer I want.

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
float interestrate;

    if (month < 49)
    {
        interestrate = (0.063);
    }
    else if (salary <= 25000)
    {
        interestrate = (0.033);
    }
    else if (salary > 45000)
    {
        interestrate = (0.063);
    }
    else
    {
        interestrate = (0.033+(salaryabovethreshold*0.0000015));
    }

    printf("Interest Rate: %d \n", interestrate);
```

Comment: it's the `printf` who is "not working". Check the format specifiers you use for printing `float`s

Comment: Ah ok. Should i use something else instead of printf?

Comment: You should use `%f` instead of `%d`. Would suggest reading [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) on `printf`

Comment: These things `%d` and `%f` etc (format specifiers) are generally addressed in chapter 1 of a beginner-level C programming book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%d` format specifier is for `int`s, not `float`s. Try `%f`, `%e` or `%g` or `%a` for floating-point types.